# How can I simulate a remote Docker locally for the Circle CI image?

Tags: docker, circleci

I'm trying to build a base image that Circle CI can use to load all my other Docker images from ECS. However, I'm having trouble simulating the remote docker environment locally when I build the image. How can I tell it to use remote Docker when in CI and local Docker when I'm local?

This is my Docker file

```
# This Docker image is solely for connecting to ECS and grabbing our other images

### Build & Push Command (Locally):
# Ask @tolicodes for what the AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY are
# export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=XXX && export AWS_SECRET_KEY=XXX
# docker build --build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY --build-arg AWS_SECRET_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_KEY -f docker_files/website-ci-base.Dockerfile -t xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/website:website-ci-base . && docker push xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/website:website-ci-base

FROM circleci/node:9.11.1-browsers

### ECS LOGIN

# Make sure that environmental variables can be accessed later
# Rename them to variables that AWS config can use
# Note: that we have to do the rename because someone specified the keys
# In the circle config with different names, and I don't want to mess with
# that -@tolicodes
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY
ARG AWS_SECRET_KEY
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_KEY

# Python is required by AWS CLI
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev

# Install and log into CLI. Now we can use ECS
RUN sudo pip install awscli
RUN $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
```

And I get the error

```
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: Maybe your local user doesn't have permissions to access de docker daemon's socket, did you tried with sudo?